# Access non contiguous RAM slots in Arduino Nicla Vision

Tags: sram

I'm working on a TinyML project with an Arduino Nicla Vision and I need to store a model with size 608kB in RAM. In the Nicla Vision datasheet, it is stated that 864kB of SRAM are available, but it is segmented in three non contiguous parts (AXI SRAM, SRAM1-3, SRAM4).
[image]

When I try to load the model in RAM, I get the error 'linker_script.ld:110 cannot move location counter backwards (from 240aa610 to 2407fc00)' because only the AXI SRAM (524kB) is used.

Is there a way to distribute the model over all the available non contiguous RAM?